# GNU Emacs paste after closing window

Tags: linux, emacs

I am running Emacs 24.5 in Gnome and using CUA keys for cut, copy, and paste. So long as the Emacs window is open I can copy and paste to and from other applications just fine. But if I copy a block of code from the Emacs window and then close it, I can no longer paste what was copied. 
I always open Emacs from the Terminal. I would like to open Emacs, copy a line, close the window, and then paste it into the terminal with the middle mouse button. But this only works if I leave Emacs open. Is there anything I can add to my .emacs file to allow me to keep my clipboard after Emacs closes?

Comment: I don't think there is; and this is hardly a common use case. Most Emacs users very rarely quit.

Comment: It's an X11 design feature. Emacs is not the culprit, you want a "clipboard manager" or something like that